# Bright semi transparent about spotify?

Tags: css, html

Recently I rebuild the [Spotify](https://www.spotify.com/us/) home page using pure Javascript and scss to test my front-end study, Here is the [link](https://quilljou.github.io/demo/imitation/spotify/dist/).It's not finished yet.
You can see the the difference between mine and the real one is the big-background, the markup is

```
<div class="bg-main">
  <sceiotn class="can-see-the-background-image-1"></section>
  <sceiotn class="can-see-the-background-image-2"></section>
</div>
```

I gave the section rgba(rgb,0.7) background,You can see the effect is not that bright as the real one,which can see the back albums clearly.I dig into their source code,But I didn't find the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

First, add the gradient to the `background` property on your element `<div class="bg-main">`:

```
.bg-main {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: url(../img/bg-albums.png) repeat, 
                linear-gradient(50deg, rgba(255, 65, 105, 1) 0, 
                rgba(124, 38, 248, 1) 100%) repeat
    position: relative;
}
```

Then, in your element `<header class="header">` remove the gradient from the `background` property:

```
.header {
    height: 760px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Explanation**
The reason Spotify's is clear to see is because the background colour gradient is on the same element as the image. So the image is superimposed on top of the background gradient.

On your site you have the image *underneath*, and then you place a faded background over the top - making it more difficult to see. With the image on top of the gradient background, it makes the album art much clearer and easier to see.

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zCz3.jpg)

Comment: Incredible, problem solved.Thanks.And what the theme your chrome devTools   is using?

Comment: No worries! Could you consider marking this as the accepted answer?
I'm not using a theme in the Chrome DevTools, as of 2 versions ago, there is a default "dark" theme bundled with Chrome. To enable it, open DevTools -> open DevTools' settings (F1) -> under Appearance, select Theme: Dark

Comment: Wait a moment. But in your way, The parallax didn't work, Spotify's big-backdound is fixed when your scoll

Comment: @Quill I was just showing you why the background wasn't clear. If you want your scroll to work as well, you'll have to move the background gradient onto the `bg-main` element. I'll update my answer. Just make sure you remove the extra background gradients on your other sections on your site, otherwise you'll have two layers of the same background gradient.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I'm new to this website, Where to set the accepted answer?

Comment: @Quill [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Got it ,I found it